# How to supply credentials for a DNN WebAPI endpoint?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, asp.net-web-api

I've got a DNN 7 website, with web service endpoints like this:

```
public class DNNRoleManagementServiceController: DnnApiController
{
    //[AllowAnonymous]
    [RequireHost]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage ManagePortalUserToRole(int PortalID, int UserID, int RoleID, bool RemoveFromRole )
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

It was AllowAnonymous for development, it's now RequireHost because security on your endpoints is good to have.  These endpoints should only be used by our system, so `[RequireHost]` seems to be the right authentication level.

I've got my c# library to call this endpoint:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri(uriString.ToString());
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("host", "password");
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += GetStringCompleted;
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

Even with the right password though, all I get is a 400 or 401 response.  So obviously I'm supplying my credentials the wrong way.  Only, what's the right way? All the documentation I've found on the DNN WebAPI has been "Apply the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute so that anyone and their dog can use your web service!" which is great if the service you're supplying is for public consumption.  This isn't one of those cases.

So what's the right method of supplying host credentials so the call will work?  I'm really not sure here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing

`[DnnAuthorize(RequireHost=true)]`

Don't know if it will work as I've only done it for actual logged in users and not from an external source passing username and password credentials.

You could maybe look at this codeplex project for some more information.

[Codeplex: dnndashservice](http://dnndashservice.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/20684#287707)